# MongoDB floating point value precision?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, floating-point, ieee-754

As I know, JavaScript uses IEEE 754 Floating point to treat real numbers.
The problem arises when using it, it's quite common issue:

> 0.1 + 0.2 = 0.30000000000000004

Most of time, using the module like 'big.js', but the problem is when using MongoDB.

Look at this document:

> { "_id" : ObjectId("58ff8f721bbfbcd140e472b3"), "value" : 0.1 }

When I run $inc like this:

> db.dec.update({ _id: ObjectId('58ff8f721bbfbcd140e472b3') }, { $inc: { value: 0.2 }});

The result is not good at all:

> { "_id" : ObjectId("58ff8f721bbfbcd140e472b3"), "value" : 0.30000000000000004 }

I know why it's happening, but is there a way to avoid this problem?

Comment: why is this a problem for you?

Comment: @Thomas Because I'm handling the currency

Comment: To me this sounds like a matter of formatting, not a problem with the numeric system. Check this: `var nr = .1 + .2;  console.log(nr, nr.toLocaleString("en", {style: "currency", currency: "USD"}))` [Number#toLocaleString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString)

Comment: the only point where these floating point errors actually are a problem, is when checking for equality `(.1 + .2) === .3`

Comment: @Thomas Okay, then how to use it in MongoDB query? Now I know what you are trying to say, but how put them in the query?

Comment: Not at all. It's the buisness of your template/renderer to take care of that kind of stuff, not of the DB. The same way you're fine with your DB returning `0.1` and don't expect it to be `"0.10"`; that would also be formatting. Write a "template" function that converts the float to the output you want (currency sign, decimal places, leading zeroes, ... whatever). Simply `float => formattedString`. And use this as a last step before outputting the value to the DOM, the console, alert, whatever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know exactly the number of decimal places you want, you can do `Number((.1+.2).toFixed(1))`. Or you could use an orm for mongodb like [mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/), and define models for your database documents, and define the precision you want with some code in your model.